# How to use notanyof in nlobjSearchFilter

Tags: suitescript

```
    var ids = ['1', '2', '3'];

    var filters = new Array();
    filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T');
    filters[4] = new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null, 'notanyof', ids);

    var searchResult = nlapiSearchRecord('creditmemo', null, filters, columns);
```

Hello I'm trying to list all credit memos but where the customer ID is not 1,2 or 3?

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper operator is "noneof".

```
new nlobjSearchFilter('entity',null,'noneof',[1,2,3]);
```